# Rounded corners on VideoView (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-videoview

I have this code for showing video on my Compose Activity:

```
@Composable
fun VideoView(videoSource: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AndroidView(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), factory = { context ->
        android.widget.VideoView(context).apply {
            setVideoPath(videoSource)
            setOnCompletionListener {
                start()
            }
            start()
        }
    })
}
```

I'm trying to get rounded corners for this View. But I can't. I already used Modifier.clip() and wrapping in a Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)). It doesn't work. What else can I do?

Comment: clip is working for me

Comment: Agree @pushpull. Clip will basically work for providing roundercornershape. Maybe you should add it explicitly like: modifier.fillMaxSize().clip(RounderCornerShape(16.dp).)

Answer (score 0):

This is my video view code.

```
AndroidView(
    factory = {
        YouTubePlayerView(it).apply {
            val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView = this
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView)
            val listener: YouTubePlayerListener = object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                    val defaultPlayerUiController = DefaultPlayerUiController(youTubePlayerView, youTubePlayer)
                    defaultPlayerUiController.showFullscreenButton(false)
                    youTubePlayerView.setCustomPlayerUi(defaultPlayerUiController.rootView)
                    youTubePlayer.loadOrCueVideo(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle, url.substringAfter("="), 0f)
                }
            }
            val options: IFramePlayerOptions = IFramePlayerOptions.Builder().controls(0).build()
            enableAutomaticInitialization = false
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(listener, options)
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
)
```

And below is the sample screenshot.

[image]